# Translate SAS code to Python of KL-divergence plot

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, translate, information-theory, sas-iml

How does the SAS code shown below look when translated into python?

```
/* Plot the K-L div versus lambda for a sequence of Poisson(lambda) models */
lambda = do(4, 16, 0.1);
KL = j(1, ncol(lambda), .);
do i = 1 to ncol(lambda);
   poisPDF = pdf("Poisson", Levels, lambda[i]);
   KL[i] = KLDiv(Proportion, poisPDF); 
end;
 
title "K-L Divergence from Poisson(lambda)";
call series(lambda, KL) grid={x y} xvalues=4:16 label={'x' 'K-L Divergence'};
```

[Source](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/05/28/minimize-kullback-leibler-divergence.html)

Comment: That is not base SAS code. Instead it is matrix code written for PROC IML.

Comment: can it be translated to python